# I can't specify the database name with Entity Framework 6.1.2 migrations

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

Here's what I did (I wanted to create a list but SO is bugged and code doesn't work after a list item for some reason):

I created  a new class library for my model.

I added reference to Entity Framework and ASP.NET Identity.Created a user class.. something like this (see that I'm specifying the connection string name):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

I created an `IdentityDbContext<>` like this:

```
public class UserHubContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserHubContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }
}
```

I specified the connection  string like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyProjectDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I ran `enable-migrations`.

I ran `add-migration initial`.

I ran `update-database`.

Result (it's not using the database I specified):

```
Target database is: 'aspnet-MyProject-20150119082112' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
```

That's really weird because I explicitly said the connection string should be `DefraultConnection` so it should use `MyProjectDb` as the database.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe it.

I have two projects in my solution. `MyProject` and `MyProject.Model`. Only the second had the right connection string. I was clearly running Nuget PowerShell commands on the `MyProject.Model`... but it was looking for the connection string on `MyProject`. Clearly a bug.

After I unloaded `MyProject` and ran the exact same commands again. Everything worked fine.

Comment: Great! I use your answer and my problem solved.Mark your post as answer.

Comment: @Mohsen.Unlimited, good to hear it helped you. I marked it as the answer.